# Assign Mock Variable Value in Unit Test

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

In Python I created a method that reads the contents of a web page and does some stuff with the contents.

I want to unit test the method using a specific http address but I don't want to have to assign the address manually in my production code and then test it.  So ideally I want to create some kind of mock object (using the Mock library) that takes the value of the http address I need so I can run my test with that value.

As a side note, the aim of the test is to verify that my code raises the correct exception with the tested http address.

So to illustrate, the code I want to test has the following form:

```
Class A

    method1()

        var1 = "wwww.something.com"
        read contents at address var1
        do stuff with contents (raise error if bad contents)
```

And I want to test the code with var1 = "wwww.somethingelse.com" in my unit test (ideally using the Mock library).

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your method takes no parameters, how could an invalid URI get passed to it? You should be testing your method by passing in the URI that is expected to cause the behavior you wish to test. Doing so would not require using `mock`.

What *would* require mock, would be if this was specifically a unit test, in which case you'd probably want to mock out the entire block of code that is making requests on the network, (say, `urllib2.urlopen`) with something that instead just doesn't do any network activity but instead spits back whatever content or HTTP error you want to test.

As a side note, it's perfectly reasonable (and advisable) to structure your actual production code in a way that makes it more testable.

Comment: thank you. In fact my method takes several parameters that are used to build the link. So if I wanted to simulate an HTTP Error how would I go about it?

Comment: You'd use the [`mock.patch`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#mock.patch) decorator to patch `yourmodule.urllib2.urlopen`, say, with a mock whose `side_effect=urllib2.HTTPError(whatever, args, you, want, for, it)`.